# Method not found in `regex::Captures<'_>`

Tags: rust

When I run this code in [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ef39ebb6cbcb5def1e7e9d51d7552aba):

```rust
use regex::Regex;
fn main() {
    let re = Regex::new(r#"regex(group)"#).unwrap();
    println!("{:?}", re.captures(r#"regexgroup"#).unwrap().get(1).unwrap().as_str());
}
```

the code snippet works. However, running this code locally I get the error:

```
error[E0599]: no method named `get` found for struct `regex::Captures` in the current scope
   |
   |  println!("{:?}", re.captures(r#"regexgroup"#).unwrap().get(1).unwrap().as_str());
   |                                                         ^^^ method not found in `regex::Captures<'_>`
```

In both cases I am using the 2018 edition of Rust and import `regex::Regex` (and nothing else from the regex crate).

I tried using `cargo clean` and importing the mentioned Struct but nothing works. In the regex doc they basically do the above thing and it definitely implements the `get` method.

Comment: What's in your Cargo.toml?

Comment: regex = "0.1.6"

Comment: Out of curiosity, how did you wind up with `regex = "0.1.6"` in your `Cargo.toml`? That version is truly ancient, and I'm curious what material led you to such a thing.

Comment: A typo; I saw that the newest version is 1.6.0 so I typed it out manually (instead of using cargos smartness to find the right version) and shifted somehow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got an old version of `regex`. [Up until v0.1.80 (and including), it did not have `get()`](https://docs.rs/regex/0.1.80/regex/struct.Captures.html). Upgrade your `regex` version (change Cargo.toml to at least `regex = "1"`), or use the [`pos()`](https://docs.rs/regex/0.1.80/regex/struct.Captures.html#method.pos) method - the name of the early `get()`, or just use indexing since you `unwrap()` anyway.